# Convert string to either integer or float in javascript

Tags: javascript, parseint, parsefloat

Is there a straightforward way to parse a string to either integer or float if I don't know if the variable is integer-number-like or decimal-number-like?

```
a = '2'; // => parse to integer
b = '2.1'; // => parse to float
c = '2.0'; // => parse to float
d = 'text'; // => don't parse
```

EDIT: It seems my question lacked the necessary context: I want to do some calculations without losing the original format (Original format thereby means integer vs. float. I don't care about the original number of decimal places):

Example:

`String containing the formatted number ('2')
 => parse to number (2.0)
 => do some calculations (2.0 + 1 = 3.0)
 => restore "original format" ('3' and not '3.0')`

If the input was 2.0 instead, the wanted result would be '3.0' (not '3').

Comment: Why do you wan't to parse? Javascript has dynamic typing. Moreover, the only numerical type it has is double.

Comment: @david a.: Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't aware of that. Still wondering why there are two functions (parseInt, parseFloat) in JavaScript if there is only one numerical type.

Comment: I think that the difference is just how the two parse the input - `parseInt()` only takes the integer part of it, while `parseFloat()` takes the decimal (and perhaps the exponent) as well. They, however, both return the same type (number, that is actually a floating-point type). See spec of JS numbers here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value . MSDN mentions the same thing here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx#Anchor_4

Comment: as there is no difference between a float and an int, you can really just do: `isNaN(val) ? val : parseFloat(val);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I finally solved it. I didn't find any other solution than to add the variable type to the variable ...

```js
var obj = {
 a: '2',
 b: '2.1',
 c: '2.0',
 d: 'text'
};
// Explicitly remember the variable type
for (key in obj) {
  var value = obj[key], type;
  if ( isNaN(value) || value === "" ) {
    type = "string";
  }
  else {
    if (value.indexOf(".") === -1) {
      type = "integer";
    }
    else {
      type = "float";
    }
    value = +value; // Convert string to number
  }
  obj[key] = {
    value: value,
    type: type
  };
}
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 21):

Multiply string which has number data with 1. You will get the **Numeric** data value.

```
var int_value = "string" * 1;
```

In your case

```
a = '2' * 1; // => parse to integer
b = '2.1' * 1; // => parse to float
c = '2.0' * 1; // => parse to float
d = 'text' * 1; // => don't parse    //NaN value
```

For last one you will get `NaN` value. Manually handle for NaN value

Comment: This is also the fastest way to do this, by far, even compared to JSON.parse.

Comment: You can also prepend a `+`, e.g. `+'2.1'` returns `2.1`.

Answer (score 10):

Just wrap it in `Number()`

`Number('123') === 123`

`Number('-123.456') === -123.456`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
function parse(x){
  return x==x*1?x*1:x
 }
```

```js
function parse(x){
  return x==x*1?x*1:x
 }
 
 console.log(parse(1),typeof parse(1))
 console.log(parse("1"),typeof parse("1"))
 console.log(parse("1.1"),typeof parse("1.1"))
 console.log(parse("1A"),typeof parse("1A"))
```