# convert variable float, integer or left as string directly - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a string variable as follows:

- the variable string is a float-> convert to float
- else string is an integer-> convert to integer
- else return string

This is what I currently tried:

```js
function parse(x){
    return x==parseFloat(x)?parseFloat(x):
           x==parseInt(x)?parseInt(x):
           x
}

console.log(typeof parse("11.5"),parse("11.5"))
console.log(typeof parse("11"),parse("11"))
console.log(typeof parse("11.5A"),parse("11.5A"))
```

I am looking for solutions if there exists a more efficient and direct way to do this.

Comment: More direct? No. (Although `parseFloat` should suffice for parsing integers as well). More efficient? Don't call `parseFloat` and `parseInt` twice, but store the result in a temporary variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to either integer or float in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544827/convert-string-to-either-integer-or-float-in-javascript)

Comment: Answers don't direct as mush as my try in the questions. Better be people try something from my try. That's why I posted this questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is more efficient:

```
function parse(x){
  return x==x*1?x*1:x
 }
```

```js
function parse(x){
      return x==x*1?x*1:x
 }
console.log(typeof parse("11.5"),parse("11.5"))
console.log(typeof parse("11"),parse("11"))
console.log(typeof parse("11.5A"),parse("11.5A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const parse = x => !isNaN(x) ? Number(x) : x

console.log(parse(1), typeof parse(1))
console.log(parse(1.5), typeof parse(1.5))
console.log(parse('1'), typeof parse('1'))
console.log(parse('1A'), typeof parse('1A'))
console.log(parse(0), typeof parse(0))
console.log(parse('0'), typeof parse('0'))
```

Comment: @Bergi well spotted. fixed.